# Create a .bat file that opens a IE 11 homepage that has a url greater than 260 characters

Tags: batch-file, ssrs-2008, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to create a .bat file that launches IE11 `start http://sas01/ReportServer?%2fScreen%2fRun+Time%2fMaintenance+Office+Live+Runtime2&rs:Command=Render&rc:toolbar=false&rs:clearssion=true` but I get error that the URL needs to be less than 260 characters.

I've set it as the homepage, but I cannot get the file to open the homepage.

I was going to start the homepage in Start up but I need it to refresh, but IE caches the information so I have thought about closing the IE down and reopening it sporadically.

```
start  http://sas01/ReportServer?%2fScreen%2fRun+Time%2fMaintenance+Office+Live+Runtime2&rs:Command=Render&rc:toolbar=false&rs:clearssion=true
ping 216.58.209.227 -n 3000
exit
TASKKILL /F /IM iexplore.exe
start runIE.bat
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Just use a URL shortener to create a small URL pointing to this long one. It's perfectly ok if that's your intranet, it should still work

Comment: or create .URL file according to http://www.fmtz.com/formats/url-file-format/article  and open it using `start "" file.url`

Comment: I'm sure it's not helping matters that the URL contains three ampersands and you aren't quoting it.  `start "" "http://etc."`  Also, within a batch script, if you want a literal percent sign, you have to double-pump it.  Replace all your `%2f` instances with `%%2f`.

Comment: On the cache side of things, you could set your report to automatically refresh on a schedule.Just set the AutoRefresh property of the report to the desired number of seconds. This way you wont have to keep force closing IE and restarting it.